# where to place my forms to follow 'DRY'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a larger application and I see that I end up repeating the same forms twice etc.

For example when you register and on edit account one is in the #new and the other is in the #edit. I'm assuming this is bad practice and it also takes up a lot of space in the view. How do I gather these forms and then just display them on both pages?

Comment: Use `partial forms`,they are mainly designed for this purpose.Refer these Guides on how to use them http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the rails generators they normally create a structure like so:

```
edit.html.erb
new.html.erb
_form.html.erb
```

Both new and edit pages render the form partial like so:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

This keeps the code dry so long as your form is the same for editing and creating. 
All partial file names begin with an underscore, and if you want a partial to be available across your whole application put it in `views/shared`.

Some reading on [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Comment: sweet. How would I go about it when they have some forms that are different. Say on edit you have change your password, however that isn't existent in #new. Or for example have 2 different texts on the submit button. On #new I'll have "create account" and edit ill have "update account"

Comment: You can put conditional logic in the view - for example you could check if the form is acting on a new record (create) or existing (edit) by calling `form.object.new_record?`.